# date difference using javascript

Tags: javascript, php

i have two fields like start date and End date. my need is i have to show the date differnce in another text box while user selecting dates from date picker. I done these much

I know, i done some mistakes. please help me.

```
Fromdate:
<input type="text" name="travelData[From_date]" id="txtFromDate" value="<?php echo readDate($travelData['From_date']); ?>"onfocus="javascript:NewCssCal('txtFromDate','ddmmyyyy')">

To date:
<input type="text" name="travelData[To_date]" id="txtToDate" value="<?php echo readDate($travelData['To_date']); ?>"onfocus="javascript:NewCssCal('txtToDate','ddmmyyyy')" onblur="calculateTourlength()">

<script type="text/javascript">
function calculateTourlength(){
var FromDate = $('#txtFromDate').val();
var ToDate = $('#txtToDate').val();
var tourLength = parseInt(ToDate) - parseInt(FromDate);
alert(tourLength);
$('#tourLength').val(tourLength);

return false;
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var startdate = $('#txtFromDate').datepicker('getDate');
var enddate   = $('#txtToDate').datepicker('getDate');
var calculate = (enddate - startdate)/1000/60/60/24;

NOTE: Be careful that end date must contain greater value
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. it showing some results now. but i need to show the number of dates   between that two days. ex: start date is 22-1-2015 and end date is 24-1-2015. now it need to show the result as 2.

Comment: $( "#txtFromDate" ).datepicker({ dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yyyy' }); have you set format

Comment: yes.format is  dd-mm-yyyy

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/khaliqq/jtzr4u3x/ I hope it works

Comment: Thank u so much for your help. its working!